# Integration testing strategy for Web API actions with attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on ASP.NET Core WebApi.  We have action methods decorated with custom attributes.  eg

```
[CheckPermission(Permissions.View)]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
}
```

CheckPermission attribute lives in shared library and will be used by other Api's too.

CheckPermisision attribute internally makes httpclient call to api to get boolean true or false and returns appropriate status code if unauthorized.

How should i approach for integration testing above action method. Am using inmemory test server to host my api in memory and then i use xunit to run test on it.  I am worried that if i do setup of data for permissions too then unit test code will be come very messy.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to skip any authorization pipeline is to treat a controller as a regular C# class under test. Just create it and call a method:

```
var controller = new FooController();

var result = await controller.Post(new PostData());
```

Things become a bit more complicated if the controller has external dependencies:

```
public class FooController : ApiController
{
    public IStore Store { get; set; }

    public FooController(IStore store)
    {
        Store = store;
    }
}
```

You can mock a dependency (unit-test way):

```
var mock = new Mock<IStore>();
var store = mock.Object;
var controller = new FooController(store);
```

Alternatively, DI can be used. Register all dependencies and the controller itself as well as in `Startup.ConfigureServices`. Then resolve a controller instance:

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddTransient<IStore, Store>();
services.AddTransient<FooController>();
var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

var controller = provider.GetService<FooController>();
```

You can register fake objects instead real ones as well.

See more examples: [Testing controllers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing).